# MGI_Lambert to WGS48 UTM33 transformation problem

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, wgs84, arcgis-10.6, lambert-conformal-conic

I tried to reproject a raster (DEM) with MGI_Lambert Projection (Austria) into WGS48 UTM33 Zone. I did it with ArcMap 10.6 using the recommended MGI_To_WGS_1984_3 transformation aswell as a transformation with QGIS 3.8 but encountered the following artefact/error upon completion of transformation:

[image: blubb]

The tiled image in the GIF is from the transformed raster (showing slope deduced from the dem) which seems to have 75x75m tiles which are slightly rotated. Those artefacts are not only visible on derivatives of the DEM but also affect for example flow-routing.

Can anybody explain what went wrong and how I can transform correctly?

Comment: Please use the Picture button to embed your image into the body of your question.

Comment: You can avoid these artefacts using a proper interpolation method.

Comment: thank you very much! Indeed it was the interpolation method. It worked fine with cubic convolution and bilinear

Comment: Feel free to post your solution as answer and accept it. It will help others having the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked fine with cubic convolution and bilinear interpolation with ArcMap 10.6.